# Facing a memory leak issue in node-oracledb 5.4.0, 5.1.0 and 4.1.0 with connection Pool

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-modules, node-oracledb

**versions we are using**

- NodeOracleDb Version: 4.1.0 / 5.1.0/ 5.4.0
- platform linux
- version v18.1.0
- arch x64
- version 5.4.0
- oracleclient 19.8.0.0.0 oracle
- DB: 19.0.0.0.ru-2021-10.rur-2021-10.r1

**Detailed Description**

When we use a connection pool(max 30 min 10) and if we are fetching records from a table which has more than 250+ columns where few are clobs. The memory keeps on increasing and this memory increase is in RSS. This memory never comes down and the app crashes with OOM after a certain time. We were initially using the loopback 3 framework with oracle client, but we were able to simulate the same using the default connectionPool code given in the sample files (https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/connectionpool.js). What we were also able to find out was this was coming mainly when we are using connection pool.

Include a runnable Node.js script that shows the problem.
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/files/9132973/oracleLeak.zip

This has insert script and create table scripts. Please run them first and then modify sample.js for DB connection.

We tested this with min pool as 10, max pool as 30 and UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE as 30

We even tried valgrind with 5.4.0 and we found that the issue is visible with definitely lost.

```
==36361== 903,607 (32,256 direct, 871,351 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4,608 of 4,615
==36361==    at 0x4C03A83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==36361==    by 0x1181F179: njsConnection_executeAsync (in /home/ubuntu/hkfps/oepy-outbound-payment-all/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb-5.4.0-linux-x64.node)
==36361==    by 0x11819C24: njsBaton_executeAsync (in /home/ubuntu/hkfps/oepy-outbound-payment-all/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb-5.4.0-linux-x64.node)
==36361==    by 0x163C973: worker (threadpool.c:122)
==36361==    by 0x58B2B42: start_thread (pthread_create.c:442)
==36361==    by 0x5943BB3: clone (clone.S:100)

=36361== LEAK SUMMARY:
==36361==    definitely lost: 32,256 bytes in 2 blocks
==36361==    indirectly lost: 871,351 bytes in 975 blocks
==36361==      possibly lost: 2,500,246 bytes in 1,397 blocks
==36361==    still reachable: 485,525,664 bytes in 30,537 blocks
==36361==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==36361==                         multipleinheritance: 48 bytes in 1 blocks
==36361==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Valgrind command which was used

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --trace-children=yes  --log-file=out_%p.log --demangle=yes --error-limit=no --show-leak-kinds=all node test5.js
```